# Console.app alternative for Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, logging, console

Is there a neater way to follow console messages in Terminal rather than `tail -f` tons of logs?

Comment: We could help you better if you explained what you mean with "neater". Less output? Better-looking output? Filtered output?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The `syslog(1)` command-line tool lets you run detailed queries against the Apple System Logger (ASL) database, which is the central clearing house for all* log messages. See the man page. To exactly emulate seeing just the console log stream, use:

```
syslog -C -w all
```

**all: Some apps still open and write their own log files directly instead of using the ASL facilities. ASL can't see those.*